# Getting the average from a list using len and avg function

Tags: average

I've created a simple list but am stuck on the formula using len to calculate the average. Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def average(numbers):
    return(numbers(sum/len))
print(average)

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: python def average(numbers):
    return (sum(numbers)/len(numbers)). still not working

Answer (score 0):

When I code (in Python 2.7.17):

```
def average (numbers): return (sum(numbers)/len (numbers))
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print average (numbers)
```

I get the expected result, i.e. `3`. Does this not work for you?

Comment: i did too. not sure what i was doing wrong to begin with. thank you